# c++ methods that return instance variables can access data in the variable but not change it, but no error is generated on compile

Tags: c++, function, return-value, instance-variables

I haven't done any C++ programming for 15 years, so I'm a bit rusty.

I've noticed that C++ methods that return instance variables can access data in the variable but not change it, but no error is generated on compile with G++.  I've attached a simple example below that illustrates the behavior.  The return of the functions that return instance variables can be used to access the information in the ivar, but when the return is used to change the ivar (e.g., `anA.aVec().push_back(100);`), the ivar isn't changed.

To clarify; Why does `anA.aVec().size()` work, while `anA.aVec().push_back(100)` does not?  Similarly, why does `anA.aB().i()` work, while `anA.aB().setI()` does not?

I can work around this, but I'm wondering:

1. Is this behavior consistent across compilers?
2. Is there an error or warning flag in GCC that will warn of this issue?
3. What is the underlying cause and/or reasoning behind the behaviour?

Here's my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class B{
    int _i = 0;

public:
    B(void){ }
    int i(void){return _i;}
    void setI(int anInt){ _i = anInt; }
};

class A{
    vector<int> _aVec;
    B _aB;

public:
    vector<int> aVec(void){ return _aVec; }
    B aB(void){ return _aB; }
    void pushBack(int anInt){ _aVec.push_back(anInt);}
    void setBI(int i){ _aB.setI(i); }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rows = 10;
    int cols = 8;
    srand(time(NULL));

    A anA;
    cout << "aVec size:" << anA.aVec().size() << "\n";
    anA.aVec().push_back(100);
    cout << "aVec size:" << anA.aVec().size() << "\n";
    anA.pushBack(100);
    cout << "aVec size:" << anA.aVec().size() << "\n";

    cout << "Bi:" << anA.aB().i() << "\n";
    anA.aB().setI(1);
    cout << "Bi:" << anA.aB().i() << "\n";
    anA.setBI(1);
    cout << "Bi:" << anA.aB().i() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
aVec size:0
aVec size:0
aVec size:1
Bi:0
Bi:0
Bi:1
```

Answer (score 3):

`anA.aVec().push_back(100)` does not "work", because `aVec` method returns a copy of the vector.

Change it to return a reference to avoid creating the copy:

```
vector<int> & aVec(void){ return _aVec; }
```

Comment: Thanks all (1201ProgramAlarm, Anton Malyshev, R Sahu, DiCri).  I fixed it by switching to a pointer, but the reference is cleaner....should have remembered that.  You don't have to think so much in Python and Java :-).

Answer (score 1):

> Why does `anA.aVec().size()` work, while `anA.aVec().push_back(100)` does not?
>   Similarly, why does `anA.aB().i()` work, while `anA.aB().setI()` does not?

`anA.aVec()` and `anA.aB()` return objects by value. A copy of the object is returned to the calling function.

`anA.aVec().size()` and `anA.aB().i()` work since they are just return a piece of information.

`anA.aVec().push_back(100)` and  `anA.aB().setI()` also work but they modify a temporary object, not the objects that are member variables of `anA`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
vector<int> aVec(void){ return _aVec; }
```

It returns a copy of _aVec, so just add "&" between after "vector" so it will be returned as reference.

```
vector<int>& aVec(void){ return _aVec; }
```